# C# FileSystemWatcher Copy folder complete

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, copying

I am using FileSystemWatcher to monitor a folder that will be used to do some file renaming.
The only thing that will be copied will be folders containing files.  There will not be single files put into the monitored folder.  This is the code for setting up the FileSystemWatcher

```
watcher.Path = path;
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName;
watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
watcher.Filter = "*.*";
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Created);
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(watcher_Renamed);
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

There doesn't seem to be any issues with this setup..

The folders being copied can be between 50-200mb big.  Is there a way to check/make sure that all the files have completed copying before starting the renaming process.
I tried this thinking that i would get an IOException if the copying was still happening when the GetFiles() was called.

```
bool finishedCopying = false;
while (!finishedCopying)
{
    try
    {
        List<FileInfo> fileList = directoryInfo.GetFiles().ToList();
        AlbumSearch newAlbum = new AlbumSearch(directoryInfo);
        return newAlbum;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        finishedCopying = false;
    }
}
```

If anymore information is required, just ask an i can provide.

Ta.

Comment: I think you're effectively asking for a time machine. `IsSomeOtherProcessPlanningToWriteMoreFilesToThisLocation` is a tricky function to write.

Comment: That is not possible.  No way to tell the difference between, say, the user temporarily pausing the program that does the moving/copying and him running it twice in a row.  You know nothing about the process that does this, do not make any assumptions.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case. I was hoping that there may have been something in the copy process that could be accessed to get information from the source folder.  Even something like the number of files...

Comment: Depending on the ability to have access to the source files and/or the system doing the writing, what you might do is calculate the checksum of the content in the folder and compare it on certain time intervals with the checksum of your destination. If they match the copying will be validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave this a go using a timer.  It may not be the prettiest solution out there but at first testing it seems to be working so far.  Essentially what this does is when a folder is copied to the monitored folder it will add the folder path to the AlbumList.  The files in that folder will trigger the Created event.  This waits for the file to finish copying.  Once finished it starts a timer.  If a new Created event gets triggered the timer will reset itself.

When the timer.elapsed event is triggered it assumes (and I know assumption is the mother of all f*&k ups) that there are no more files to be copied and can start to process the fully copied folder..

```
System.Timers.Timer eventTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(); 
List<string> AlbumList = new List<string>();

private void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{    
    if (Directory.Exists(e.FullPath))
    {
        AlbumList.Add(e.FullPath);
    }

    if (File.Exists(e.FullPath))
    {
        eventTimer.Stop();
        FileInfo newTrack = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        while (IsFileLocked(newTrack))
        {
            // File is locked. Do Nothing..
        }
        eventTimer.Start();              
    }
}

private void eventTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> ItemToRemove = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in AlbumList)
    {            
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(item);
        AlbumSearch newAlbum = new AlbumSearch(di);

        if (DoSomethingMethod(newAlbum))
        {
            ItemToRemove.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            // why did it fail
        }
    }

    foreach (var path in ItemToRemove)
    {
        AlbumList.Remove(path);
    }
}

private bool DoSomethingMethod(AlbumSearch as)
{
    // Do stuff here 
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small demo app that check files at the beginning, and then uses two hashsets to track copied files. This will only work if the source directory is known. There is no way to know if a file was created from a file copy or from a direct creation, so you can only compare two known directories with Directory.GetFiles. And, as already said in comments, you will still have to check if during the copy process, other files were added / removed /  renamed in the old directory

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static HashSet<string> oldDirFiles = new HashSet<string>();
        static HashSet<string> newDirFiles = new HashSet<string>();

        static string oldDir = "C:\\New Folder";
        static string newDir = "C:\\New Folder 2";

        static System.Threading.ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = newDir;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName;
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            watcher.Created += watcher_Created;
            watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;
            watcher.Renamed += watcher_Renamed;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            //get all files in old directory
            var oldFiles = Directory.GetFiles(oldDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (var file in oldFiles)
                oldDirFiles.Add(file);

            resetEvent.WaitOne();

            //now launch the directory copy

            //then you have to check if in the meaning time, new files were added or renamed
            //that could be done also with a watcher in the old directory
        }

        static void watcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        static void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        static void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            //check if the copied file was in the old directory before starting
            if (oldDirFiles.Contains(e.FullPath.Replace(newDir, oldDir)))
            {
                newDirFiles.Add(e.FullPath);
                //if all the files have been copied, the file count will be the same in the two hashsets
                //the resetevent.Set() signal the waiting thread and the program can proceed
                if (newDirFiles.Count == oldDirFiles.Count)
                    resetEvent.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So far as I understand the OPs question, their's isn't the code *doing* the copying. As such, there's no easy way to find the source of the copying (and hence the comments about the difficulty - if it's their own code doing the copying, then just arrange for that code to send a "done" signal of some sort at the end - no need to FSW at all)

Comment: I also think that, otherwise you just wait your copy process to finish, no need any sort of waiting / threading etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That is correct, my code does no copying.  I will be manually dragging a folder into the monitored folder, so windows will be handling the copying.

Comment: My application is actually intended to monitor a file copy from outside (eg: from windows copy). Try the application and start copy when the program stops at the resetEvent.WaitOne(); line. Then see if you can use this approach in your solution.

Comment: Another approach could be that on the three events (Renamed, Changed and Created) you check the file list on both source and destination directory (with Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) and compare them. When all files in the source directory are also in the destination directory, the file copy is completed.

Comment: @StefanoCastriotta If I am copying a folder into the FSW monitored folder using the Windows GUI copy (not a code generated copy) how am I able to get the information from the source folder to be able to do a comparison?

Comment: If the source is unknown, there's no way, my code was intended to work with known source and destination. How can you know in a "File created" event if the file was created from a file copy or from anything else?