# c# filesystemwatcher move detection

Tags: c#, move, filesystemwatcher

I want to replicate all changes to a given folder. I use the FileSystemWatcher in C# and I can detect most changes. One type of change that I cannot detect easily is a move of a complete folder to the watched folder. I receive only a create-event for the folder but no events for the content of that moved folder. I can think of some logic to figure out if it is a move or just a creation of a new folder, but it seems awkward that it is quite hard to do this. Any suggestions in easy/out-of-the-box folder-move detection?

Thans a lot!

Comment: You may want to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678108/c-sharp-filesystemwatcher-copy-folder-complete)

Comment: Possible duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286114/detecting-moved-files-using-filesystemwatcher

Comment: @HerbalMart: that question handles more about detecting a move within the monitored folder. Solutions are to figure out the move-scenario based on the delete+create events. Though, when a move happens from outside the monitored folder, you do not get a delete-event and thus you cannot use that for move-detection...

Answer (score 1):

> I receive only a create-event for the folder but no events for the content of that moved folder.

That's correct as OS does not "copy+delete" the folder internals. It's just "relink" the folder in the file system. As just a 'fast' idea - you cold check if 'created' folder is empty or not at the moment the create event received. If the folder is not empty you cold assume it was moved.

Comment: yes that is what I am doing right now, but I thought there had to be some way to get this info from the FileSystemWatcher framework.

Comment: Only issue is when operations are automated (copying, moving...) by applications, it is harder to tell if the files are copied just after the folder creation or if it was a move. I have a rather complex mechanism to find that out and I hoped to get the complexity out of that and use a out-of-the-box solution. I guess I will have to stick with my mechanism.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to make a file system filter driver in order to achieve true control over file system.

Comment: Btw, did you test how your solution works with network mapped drives? I'd suggest to do that as there can be issues potentially.

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468637/filesystemwatcher-not-raising-when-files-are-copied-or-moved-to-folder